# API authtentication with a Ionic app

Tags: api, authentication, ionic-framework

I am building a Ionic app that is supposed to communicate with an ASP net MVC application (I need to get JSON data).

When I send request to the ASP application from the Ionic app, I am not allowed because I am not logged. I get this :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

My issue is that I want to log in to my API but I do not know how to proceed with Ionic. In a similar application, I used C# client and I was using an **HttpWebRequest** & **NetworkCredential** objects.

I made POST request to try to log in the API but I just get a 401 error.
Here is the code, but the credentials that I sent do not allow me to authenticate to the web service.

```
connect(){

    var credentials = "name=" + mylogin + "&password=" + mypassword;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    this.http.post(URLServeur, credentials, {headers: headers}).subscribe(data => {
        if(data.json().success){
            console.log("yes");
            resolve(true);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no");
            resolve(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I precise that even when I try to access to my API from browser, it asks an authentication (Login and password). It is a windows authentication. I would like to be able to log in from  the Ionic app with a post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found out that it is an issue in Angular with the parameters of the request. If you insert too much request options, withCredentials : true is ignored.

Code in Ionic app:

```
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var url = "http://localhost"
    var data = "This is my data";

    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {withCredentials: true}).subscribe(data => {
        if(data){
            console.log("yes");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("no");
        }
    });
```

Also, do not forget to add this to webConfig file on server :

```
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8100" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-Type,authorization" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
     </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

I hope it will help other people

Comment: to be clear there is no issue with Angular. You need to look into how http requests work in Angular and you wont have this problem.